# GitLab for Slack App: notification to a specific branch

Tags: gitlab, notifications, integration, slack

I am using the Integration tool GitLab for Slack App and want to only send a notification when code is pushed to a specific branch.  Is there a way to only send a notification when an action is done to a specific branch?

I have already searched through the Gitlab documentation and only see that notifications can be sent from default branches and protected branches.  Considering I have a few protected branches, this option does not work for me.  [image: Notification Settings].

Answer (score 0):

That still does not seem possible.

[GitLab 16.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/02/15/gitlab-16-9-released/#rest-api-support-for-the-gitlab-for-slack-app) (February 2024) comes with:

> ### REST API support for the GitLab for Slack app
>
> With this release, we’ve added REST API support for the GitLab for Slack app.
>
> You cannot create a GitLab for Slack app from the API. Instead, you must [install the app](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/gitlab_slack_application.html#install-the-gitlab-for-slack-app) from the GitLab UI. You can then retrieve the integration settings and update or disable the app for a project.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/integrations.html#gitlab-for-slack-app) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/364440).

But [that API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/integrations.html#gitlab-for-slack-app) only reflects what you previously saw with the GUI:

> ### `branches_to_be_notified`
>
> Branches to send notifications for.
> Valid options are:
>
> - `all`,
> - `default` (default),
> - `protected`,
>   and `default_and_protected`.

You still cannot specify a specific branch.